# Elasticsearch - Score word match w/partial word

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search

I am new with elasticsearch and I am having trouble getting the score I want on the results.

This is the best working options I got so far.

```
$options['query']['bool']['should'][] = [
    'match' => [
        'my_long_textfield' => [
            'query' => $query,
            'operator' => 'AND',
            'boost' => 15
        ]
    ]
];

$options['query']['bool']['should'][] = [
    'match' => [
        'my_long_textfield' => [
            'query' => $query,
            'minimum_should_match' => '80%'
        ]
    ]
];
```

**Example dataset (two rows):**

```
my_long_textfield:
"some cars move fast"
"a car can move quickly"
```

If my query is "car fast" it will give the second row the highest score, since the first row contains "car" instead of "cars".

I would like to give score on word matches as well as partial words.

So with the query "car fast", we have a match on the word "fast" and "car" is allmost a word match in the first row. And this should score higher then only one word match on the second row.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach the problem, but the easiest one is to leverage analyzers. In your case, you could configure `my_long_textfield` to use the [`english` language analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer), which in addition to removing stop words, also does stemming (i.e. index `car` for `cars`), which is what you need here (before diving into fuzziness).

So, first create your index with the proper analyzer for the field:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_long_textfield": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then index two test documents:

```
POST test/_doc/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{ "my_long_textfield": "some cars move fast" }
{ "index": {}}
{ "my_long_textfield": "a car can move quickly" }
```

Then, your query will get you exactly what you expect, i.e. the first document with a higher score than the second:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "my_long_textfield": {
              "query": "car fast",
              "operator": "AND",
              "boost": 15
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "my_long_textfield": {
              "query": "car fast",
              "minimum_should_match": "80%"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Results =>

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "w3uIlm0B0Vd4Dh649_Vg",
    "_score" : 14.0075,
    "_source" : {
      "my_long_textfield" : "some cars move fast"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "xHuIlm0B0Vd4Dh649_Vg",
    "_score" : 0.18232156,
    "_source" : {
      "my_long_textfield" : "a car can move quickly"
    }
  }
]
```

If you think a little bit further, we could also add a [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms) because `fast` and `quick` do mean the same thing, but that's another discussion.